# Why can't I connect to my remote MySQL Server?

Tags: mysql, iptables

I have a asterisk server that is set up in on a VPS provider.  I need one of my local applications to connect to the database to pull reports, but I am having dificulty getting a read only connection to work.

I can see that the server is listening on port 3306:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
```

I have created a firewall exception:

```
 Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 12 packets, 2400 bytes)
 num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 1     7326 1439K ELASTIX_INPUT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

 Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 1        0     0 ELASTIX_FORWARD  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

 Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 215M packets, 43G bytes)
 num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 1     7280 1542K ELASTIX_OUTPUT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

 Chain ELASTIX_FORWARD (1 references)
 num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 1        0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

 Chain ELASTIX_INPUT (1 references)
 num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 1        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       173.###.##.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:3306 dpt:3306
 2        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 3        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 4        0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpts:67:68
 5       22  9834 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpts:5004:5082
 6        0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:4569
 7        0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:5036
 8     7065 1411K ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpts:10000:20000
 9        0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:2727
 10       0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp spt:53
 11       0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:69
 12       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:25
 13       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:110
 14       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:143
 15      22  1857 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       173.##.##.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:443
 16       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:993
 17       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:995
 18       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:5222
 19       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:9090
 20     206 14216 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
 21       3   152 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

I have a read only user created:

```
GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO 'read_only'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '******************'
```

But I continue to get the error :

```
Error number: 2003
Can't connect to MySQL server on '209.###.##.##' (0)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Since rule order is critical in `iptables` rules, showing us a single rule is utterly pointless.  If you suspect the firewall, please cut-and-paste into your question the output of `iptables -L -n -v --line-numbers`.

Comment: @MadHatter  Thank you for your help.  I have included the full iptables now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the client connection won't come **from** port 3306, but instead from a randomly-assigned ephemeral source port.  Remove the `--sport 3306` and your listed servers should be able to connect.